# Bad values with gdalwarp and "aliased" coordinate transformation

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp, epsg, vrt

I've strange values using gdallocationinfo on vrt with coordinate system transformation.
Here is my use case, maybe you can help to understand what I did bad or misunderstood

**1) I've got a bunch of big geotiff (French IGN rge alti)**

```
> gdalinfo.exe -proj4 RGEALTI_2-0_1M_COG_LAMB93-IGN69_D001_2020-11-13.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: RGEALTI_2-0_1M_COG_LAMB93-IGN69_D001_2020-11-13.tif
Size is 111000, 101000
Coordinate System is:
COMPOUNDCRS["RGF93 v1 / Lambert-93 + NGF-IGN69 height",
    PROJCRS["RGF93 v1 / Lambert-93",
...
        BBOX[42.33,-4.87,51.14,8.23]],
    ID["EPSG",5698]]
...
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-99999
  Unit Type: metre
```

**2) I create a vrt file for all tif in EPSG 5698**

```
> gdalbuildvrt -overwrite -srcnodata -99999 -vrtnodata -99999 -a_srs epsg:5698 rgealti_2-0_1m_5698.vrt *.tif
```

**3) To query data throught gdal api (in php wrapper https://github.com/nono303/php-ogr) in wgs84 - without coordinate system transformation - I wrap previous vrt to:**

```
> gdalwarp -srcnodata -99999 -dstnodata -99999 -of VRT -s_srs epsg:5698 -t_srs epsg:4326 rgealti_2-0_1m_5698.vrt rgealti_2-0_1m_5698-4326.vrt
> gdalwarp -srcnodata -99999 -dstnodata -99999 -of VRT -s_srs epsg:2154 -t_srs epsg:4326 rgealti_2-0_1m_5698.vrt rgealti_2-0_1m_2154-4326.vrt
```

Fyi :
EPSG:2154 https://epsg.io/2154 RGF93 v1 / Lambert-93

```
> gdalsrsinfo --single-line -o proj4 EPSG:2154
+proj=lcc +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

EPSG:5698 https://epsg.io/5698 RGF93 v1 / Lambert-93 + NGF-IGN69 height

```
> gdalsrsinfo --single-line -o proj4 EPSG:5698
+proj=lcc +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +vunits=m +no_defs
```

**4) In my understand, coordinate system transformation might be the same from 4326 to 2154 or 5698. But when I query my 3 vrt file, the once wrapped in 5698 return a bad value**

```
> gdallocationinfo -wgs84 F:/maps/dem/rgealti_2-0_1m/rgealti_2-0_1m_5698.vrt 6.88715435 45.87902915
Report:
  Location: (691378P,572540L)
  Band 1:
    <LocationInfo><File>F:/maps/dem/rgealti_2-0_1m\RGEALTI_2-0_1M_COG_LAMB93-IGN69_D073_2020-10-15.tif</File><File>F:/maps/dem/rgealti_2-0_1m\RGEALTI_2-0_1M_COG_LAMB93-IGN69_D074_2020-10-15.tif</File></LocationInfo>
    Value: 3751.25
```

```
> gdallocationinfo -wgs84 F:/maps/dem/rgealti_2-0_1m/rgealti_2-0_1m_2154-4326.vrt 6.88715435 45.87902915
Report:
  Location: (874229P,483400L)
  Band 1:
    Value: 3751.25
```

Bad one:

```
> gdallocationinfo -wgs84 F:/maps/dem/rgealti_2-0_1m/rgealti_2-0_1m_5698-4326.vrt 6.88715435 45.87902915
Report:
  Location: (874229P,483400L)
  Band 1:
    Value: 3804.48852539062
```

Any explanation or clue to understand it would be welcome